# Restrict access to wordpress page depending on Google login

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I want to make two pages on company's intranet we have on Wordpress. First page is for all, so no problem here, but the second one should be available only to Managers. We use Google environment and I though that this solution, to make it automated, could grant access based on a set alias that aggregates all the managers.

I found the [s2Member](https://wordpress.org/plugins/s2member/#description) plugin but it's not exactly what I'm looking for.

Thanks in advance for any hints, recommendations on plugins etc.

Answer (score 1):

A simple option would be to [protect the page with a password](https://wordpress.org/documentation/article/protect-posts-with-password/) and only share the password with those select people.

But, it makes sense to tie to existing logins - one way to do that with Google would be:

1. Make the page [Private](https://wordpress.org/documentation/article/post-status/)
2. Set up a plugin like [Log in with Google](https://wordpress.org/plugins/login-with-google/) - or possibly [something fancier](https://wordpress.org/plugins/miniorange-saml-20-single-sign-on/) if you want full SAML with group/role mapping.
3. Set all managers up as Administrators on the site

If you prefer not to make them all admins, you could use an additional plugin to limit access based on specific roles.  [Content Control](https://wordpress.org/plugins/content-control/) looks like it could be a good fit.

Comment: Thank you very much - I'll check those recommendations for sure!